# Checking multiple files at one using prettier

Tags: prettier

I'm trying to run the Prettier CLI tool and what I wanted to do is running it against multiple files at once, is that possible?

I know we can use glob patterns but those files not be easily matched to a pattern. Because I'm trying to run the CLI tool against staged files in a pre-commit hook.

So I was hoping to do something like: `prettier --write "file.js, src/file2.js, src/somepath/file2.js"`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use curly brackets:

```
prettier --write "src/file{1,2}.js"
```

In your example:

```
prettier --write "{file1,src/file2,src/somepath/file2}.js"
```

It might be simpler just write out a list of files:

```
prettier --write -- file1.js src/file2.js src/somepath/file2.js
```

(`--` is explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash)